# Proving that, if the unit ball $B_Y$ of Y is a closed set, then $Y$ is a closed subspace.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Considering a normed space $X$ and $Y$ a proper subspace of $X$, I need to prove that, if the unit ball $B_Y = \{ y \in Y : \|y\| \leq 1\} $ is a closed subset of X, then $Y$ is a closed subspace of $X$. 
I've actually proven the inverse of that statement, but I have no clue how to prove this one.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start with the definition of $Y$ being  closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(x_n)_n$ is a sequence in $Y$ that converges to some $x \in X$ then the sequence is bounded, so there is some $K>0$ such that $||x_n||\leq K$ for all $n.$
Let $y_n=x_n/K \in Y $. The $||y_n||\leq 1 $ for all $n$ so $y_n \in B_Y.$ We know $B_Y$ is closed so $y_n$ must converge to some $ y \in B_Y.$ But $x_n=Ky_n $ so $x_n$ converges to $ky$ which is in $Y$ as $Y$ itself is a vector space so closed under scalar multiplication.